# Uniquely identify FI in here traffic responses

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I am checking the traffic flow api mentioned below of here maps. 
traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?bbox=12.9181%2C77.6218%3B12.9163%2C77.6239&app_id=<>&app_code=<>

How do I uniquely identify the flow items. There is some PC (TMC point code) which I thought of considering, but not able to understand if that will be unique across area/city/country. Is PC unique across a city? I am new to TMC concept. Is it like a country is divided into TMC tables and PC is unique in a given table?

Answer (score 0):

TMC is country specific. You can refer to https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/resource-type-tmc-code.html for understanding TMC Code Types. It is a fixed 5 characters of the below format ECC+CCD+Table , where the following rules apply: ECC is the Extended Country Code. CCD is the TMC country code. Table is the defined TMC Table

For example, to filter for the New England region in the USA, concatenate the US extended country code (A0) with the TMC country code (1) and the New England region table ID (29), producing the following parameter/value pair:

&tables=A0129

Comment: What about PC in it? is that unique for a given area/city?